# Selenium can't make 2 try functions python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

i can't get my code working, i need for code to try first element, then other element if there is neither of them then i need it to refresh browser and start again. Link is removed by me.

Code:

```
carnr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rn_find"]')
piet = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="doVRAA"]/a')
driver.get("https://link")
while True:
    try:
        carnr #1 lapa
        carnr.send_keys(mnr)
        carnrPoga = driver.find_element_by_name("RnFind").click()
        break
    except:
        try:
            piet.click() #TODO
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
```

error code:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'except' statement on line 28
PS C:\Users\rektl\Desktop\csdd projekts> & C:/Users/rektl/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/rektl/Desktop/csdd projekts/test3.py"
  File "c:\Users\rektl\Desktop\csdd projekts\test3.py", line 29
    driver.refresh()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'except' statement on line 28
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't get my code working"? You described what you need your code to do, but what does it do instead? What's the problem? Note that `driver.refresh()` should be further indented.

Comment: It shows error i posted here

Comment: the error message says that `driver.refresh()` should be indented

Comment: ohh, true, thank you :d

Comment: Similar to the above comments. Check your code first. The error you are showing is from not having your code properly formatted to function.

Also, the `find_element` selenium function will throw an error, even if it's used to set a value for the variable, if that element doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: error explains all - you have wrong indentation in line `driver.refresh()` - it need space(s) to put this line inside `except`